# Alternative way to say "days are never the same"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I would like to convey the idea that a day is never the same as the day before in other words days are always  different, so one way I came up with is:

1. days are always different among each other

would that option be correct?

Comment: "days are never the same" is better.  It's shorter, clearer and more correct.  By the way, there's no need to tag both [tag:american-english] and [tag:british-english]

Comment: *The work[load] varies / is varied.* But there are many different ways of saying much the same thing, some of which may have nuances that others don't. What *exactly* is different about the days in your context? Is the context even work-related in the first place?

Comment: @FumbleFinger, acctually the intention just say every day is different quoting SegNerd. And the reason for that is just practice English, I belive building setences heps with that. But what you've said about  nuances in different ways is very interesting

Comment: I have no idea what *every day is different quoting SegNerd* means. I  still don't know whether your context is work-related or not - or what *kind* of things vary from day to day.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I mean in the general. there are thing you do every day like work school etc. but the next day is not the exact repeat from the day before right? so that is the sense. and that is the context I want to apply my setence

Comment: To paraphrase what someone said sometime, "Each day is a fresh hell."

Answer (score 2):

The statement “days are always different among each other” is grammatically correct, but it is so needlessly wordy that it sounds odd.

I would suggest simply saying

**Every day is different**